# Primefaces ExceptionHandler not working when view expired

Tags: ajax, primefaces, jsf-2, exceptionhandler

My code is set up like https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/exceptionHandler.xhtml (only 1 button for ajax "throw view expired" implemented) and when I press that button, the dialog correctly pops up.

p:ajaxExceptionHandler is registered for 2 types, 1) javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException, 2) java.lang.Throwable

But when I wait until view actually expires and press the SAME button, no dialog pops up.  Browser debug tells me the ajax reponse is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response id="j_id1"><changes>
<update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0">
<![CDATA[6471455189255501776:-1615342152081763452]]>
</update></changes></partial-response>
```

What can go wrong?

Comment: Is this on Wildfly maybe? I think Wildfly handle session expired differently... tested on Wildfly 10.1.final and Wildfly 11.0.final.

Comment: I see in logs Wildfly will intercept unauthorized requests before FacesServlet and forward to login page...